# App is crashing while loading request in UIWebVIew - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, ios10

I am loading an URL to my `webView` but just  after starting `loadRequest` my App is crashing.

My `WebView` is inside a custom `UIView` Class with `XIB` and I am adding my view like this:

```
  WebViewContainer *webViewContainer = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WebViewContainer" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
[webViewContainer startLoadingURL:kPersonalWebsiteURL];
webViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight);

[self.view addSubview:webViewContainer];
```

My `startLoadingURL` method:

```
 - (void)startLoadingURL:(NSString *)url
 {
NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
 }
```

Here is the Interface Builder Configuration:

[image]

Here is the Error Message i am only getting this error  message not getting any logs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to retype `nil` to `self` as the owner parameter. So you may have to  replace:

```
WebViewContainer *webViewContainer = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WebViewContainer" owner:nil options:nil]
```

with

```
WebViewContainer *webViewContainer = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WebViewContainer" owner:self options:nil]
```

Comment: @pedroun it works... :) what was the reason to crash .

Comment: Glad to help. Setting an owner to `self` means that a controller, that instantiates the nib, is standing as delegate for web view.

Comment: @pedroun But in my `WebViewContainer` I have conform the `UIWebViewDelegate` and also `self.webView.delegate = self` . even then it was crashing.

Comment: Yes, because both are needed.

Comment: I have written both in my `WebViewContainer` . Is their any restriction that UIView can not handle WebView Delegate or something like that